# Flask app returns 500 error after Heroku deployment

Tags: python, flask, heroku, sqlalchemy

I have a flask app created and deployed to Heroku. When I access the root of the application, I get a 500 error. I am expecting a 400 error. I cannot understand the issue.

The repo is here: [github](https://github.com/Zlindberg06/Flask-Rest-API)

The Heroku logs are here:

```
    ›   Warning: heroku update available from 7.52.0 to 7.53.0.
2021-05-05T13:37:17.655667+00:00 app[web.1]: return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.655667+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.655668+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.655668+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
2021-05-05T13:37:17.655669+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.658503+00:00 app[web.1]: {address space usage: 97697792 bytes/93MB} {rss usage: 42188800 bytes/40MB} [pid: 7|app: 0|req: 1/1] 10.13.148.247 () {58 vars in 1105 bytes} [Wed May  5 13:37:17 2021] GET / => generated 290 bytes in 113 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 99 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.659383+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/" host=zack-flask-rest-api.herokuapp.com request_id=5cae59c8-5c7c-4e88-9bf6-749f6312e0ed fwd="24.30.21.69" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=427ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876339+00:00 app[web.1]: [2021-05-05 13:37:17,874] ERROR in app: Exception on /favicon.ico [GET]
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876351+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876353+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3208, in _wrap_pool_connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876384+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876386+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 301, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876387+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876387+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 761, in _checkout
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876388+00:00 app[web.1]: fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876388+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 419, in checkout
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876389+00:00 app[web.1]: rec = pool._do_get()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876389+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 259, in _do_get
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876389+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._create_connection()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876408+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 247, in _create_connection
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876409+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876409+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in __init__
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876410+00:00 app[web.1]: self.__connect()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876410+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876411+00:00 app[web.1]: pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876411+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876411+00:00 app[web.1]: compat.raise_(
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876412+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876412+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876412+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876413+00:00 app[web.1]: connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876413+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876414+00:00 app[web.1]: return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876414+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876415+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876415+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876415+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876416+00:00 app[web.1]: The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876416+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876417+00:00 app[web.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876417+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2447, in wsgi_app
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876418+00:00 app[web.1]: response = self.full_dispatch_request()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876418+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1945, in full_dispatch_request
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876419+00:00 app[web.1]: self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876419+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1993, in try_trigger_before_first_request_functions
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876419+00:00 app[web.1]: func()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876420+00:00 app[web.1]: File "./run.py", line 8, in create_tables
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876420+00:00 app[web.1]: db.create_all()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876421+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1094, in create_all
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876421+00:00 app[web.1]: self._execute_for_all_tables(app, bind, 'create_all')
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876421+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/flask_sqlalchemy/__init__.py", line 1086, in _execute_for_all_tables
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876422+00:00 app[web.1]: op(bind=self.get_engine(app, bind), **extra)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876422+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/schema.py", line 4744, in create_all
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876423+00:00 app[web.1]: bind._run_ddl_visitor(
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876423+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3074, in _run_ddl_visitor
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876423+00:00 app[web.1]: with self.begin() as conn:
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876424+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2990, in begin
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876424+00:00 app[web.1]: conn = self.connect(close_with_result=close_with_result)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876425+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3162, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876425+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._connection_cls(self, close_with_result=close_with_result)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876426+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 92, in __init__
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876426+00:00 app[web.1]: else engine.raw_connection()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876427+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3241, in raw_connection
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876427+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._wrap_pool_connect(self.pool.connect, _connection)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876427+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3211, in _wrap_pool_connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876428+00:00 app[web.1]: Connection._handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection(
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876440+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 2061, in _handle_dbapi_exception_noconnection
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876440+00:00 app[web.1]: util.raise_(
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876441+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876441+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 3208, in _wrap_pool_connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876442+00:00 app[web.1]: return fn()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876442+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 301, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876443+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionFairy._checkout(self)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876443+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 761, in _checkout
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876443+00:00 app[web.1]: fairy = _ConnectionRecord.checkout(pool)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876444+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 419, in checkout
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876444+00:00 app[web.1]: rec = pool._do_get()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876445+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/impl.py", line 259, in _do_get
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876445+00:00 app[web.1]: return self._create_connection()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876445+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 247, in _create_connection
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876446+00:00 app[web.1]: return _ConnectionRecord(self)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876446+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 362, in __init__
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876447+00:00 app[web.1]: self.__connect()
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876447+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 605, in __connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876447+00:00 app[web.1]: pool.logger.debug("Error on connect(): %s", e)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876448+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 70, in __exit__
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876448+00:00 app[web.1]: compat.raise_(
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876449+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 211, in raise_
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876449+00:00 app[web.1]: raise exception
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/pool/base.py", line 599, in __connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876450+00:00 app[web.1]: connection = pool._invoke_creator(self)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876450+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/create.py", line 578, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876451+00:00 app[web.1]: return dialect.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876451+00:00 app[web.1]: File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/default.py", line 584, in connect
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876452+00:00 app[web.1]: return self.dbapi.connect(*cargs, **cparams)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876452+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
2021-05-05T13:37:17.876452+00:00 app[web.1]: (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/14/e3q8)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.877300+00:00 app[web.1]: {address space usage: 97697792 bytes/93MB} {rss usage: 42188800 bytes/40MB} [pid: 7|app: 0|req: 2/2] 10.13.148.247 () {54 vars in 988 bytes} [Wed May  5 13:37:17 2021] GET /favicon.ico => generated 290 bytes in 6 msecs (HTTP/1.1 500) 2 headers in 99 bytes (1 switches on core 0)
2021-05-05T13:37:17.878386+00:00 heroku[router]: at=info method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zack-flask-rest-api.herokuapp.com request_id=2646f70c-ec4b-4757-9e16-895558a2abd0 fwd="24.30.21.69" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=8ms status=500 bytes=389 protocol=https
```

It's referencing the run.py file and `db.create_all()`. Not sure what the issue is. Here's run.py:

```
from app import app
from db import db

db.init_app(app)

@app.before_first_request
def create_tables():
    db.create_all()
```

Here's my app.py file:

```
import os
from flask import Flask
from flask_restful import Api # type: ignore
from flask_jwt import JWT # type: ignore
from security import authenticate, identity
from resources.user import UserRegister
from resources.item import Item, ItemList
from resources.store import Store, StoreList

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = os.environ.get("Database_URL", "sqlite:///mydata.db") 
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_TRACK_MODIFICATIONS"] = False
app.secret_key = "zack"
api = Api(app)
jwt = JWT(app, authenticate, identity)

api.add_resource(Store, "/store/<string:name>")
api.add_resource(Item, "/item/<string:name>")
api.add_resource(ItemList, "/items")
api.add_resource(StoreList, "/stores")
api.add_resource(UserRegister, "/register")



if __name__ == "__main__":
    from db import db
    db.init_app(app)
    app.run(port=5000, debug=True)
```

Comment: What was the actual, exact error message? You clipped off possibly relevant logs above and below the posted logs. "*The above exception was...*" What was the above exception? And the end of the Traceback should show an error message with the raised Exception.

Comment: Apologies. I've updated the logs.

Comment: Please don't edit the main content of the question. This makes the answers/comments out of context. Add any updates/changes at the end of the question instead.

Answer (score 0):

When working with deploying your project to Heroku, you will need to make sure that the database URI that you provide is valid.
In your case, the database URI:

```
app.config["SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI"] = "sqlite:////Users/zack.lindberg/Documents/section7/code/mydata.db"
```

is actually relative to your machine. This path may not exist on the Heroku Dyno, which might be one reason for its failure.

Changing the path to something like this might be a temporary fix:

```
app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///app.db'
```

But while SQLite is a good choice for local development/testing, Heroku uses a filesystem that clears its content every [24 hours](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sqlite3#disk-backed-storage). In that case, you would lose your data. They suggest to use their [Postgres database](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/flask-memcache#set-up-a-postgresql-database) which is persistent

**UPDATE:**

As highlighted by the following line in the updated log:

```
2021-05-05T13:37:17.655668+00:00 app[web.1]: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (sqlite3.OperationalError) unable to open database file
```

Confirms my initial assumption and you should consider updating the path to your SQLite db file as mentioned or use Postgresql as Heroku suggests.

Comment: Ok I've gone ahead and updated the SQLite db path. it's updated in my original post.I still seem to be getting the 500 error. `sqlite3.OperationalError: unable to open database file`

Comment: In such case please try using the PostgreSQL database addon.`heroku addons:create heroku-postgresql:hobby-dev`. Then changing your `os.environ.get("Database_URL", "sqlite:///mydata.db")` to `os.environ.get("DATABASE_URL", "sqlite:///mydata.db")`
This should make it use the Heroku PostgreSQL database.
[Heroku Docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql#provisioning-heroku-postgres)